# exult, etymological order

Tags: etymology

I checked etymology for exult in etymonline. Details are:

> 1560s, "to leap up;"
> 1590s, "to rejoice, triumph,"

> from French exulter,
> from Latin exultare/exsultare
> "rejoice exceedingly, revel, vaunt, boast;" literally "leap about, leap up,"

> frequentative of exsilire "to leap up,"
> from ex "out" (see ex-) + salire "to leap" (see salient (adj.)).

I have following questions: pls help clarify. thanks

1. with in 30 years the meaning changes from “to leap up” to “to rejoice, triumph”? how this transformation is so fast?
2. from French or Latin? Is this possible to come both from French and Latin simultaneously?
3. frequentative of exsilire? what does this mean?

frequentative details from wiki:

> In grammar, a frequentative form (abbreviated freq or fr) of a word is one that indicates repeated action, but is not to be confused with iterative aspect.The frequentative form can be considered a separate but not completely independent word called a frequentative. The frequentative is no longer productive in English, but still is in some language groups, such as Finno-Ugric, Balto-Slavic, Turkic, etc.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequentative

Comment: 1) Leap is the literal original meaning from which    the  figurative meaning rejoice ( when you are very happy you jump for joy). 2) Originally from Latin exultare, later from French exulter (French derives from Latin). 3)  Similar in meaning  and form (frequentative) to exsilire.

Comment: @user 66974 thanks. 1. ok with figurative meaning. 2. Main source is latin. 3. understood now what is frequentative and updated the question with the wiki link. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment from user 66984 answers my three questions.

> 1. Leap is the literal original meaning from which the figurative meaning rejoice ( when you are very happy you jump for joy).
> 2. Originally from Latin exultare, later from French exulter (French derives from Latin).
> 3. Similar in meaning and form (frequentative) to exsilire

frequentative details from wiki:

> In grammar, a frequentative form (abbreviated freq or fr) of a word is one that indicates repeated action, but is not to be confused with iterative aspect.The frequentative form can be considered a separate but not completely independent word called a frequentative. The frequentative is no longer productive in English, but still is in some language groups, such as Finno-Ugric, Balto-Slavic, Turkic, etc.
> https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequentative